# Spring - how to @Autowire a bean WITHOUT calling ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Is it possible to autowire the beans without calling:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

Comment: No. Atleast one Spring Context needs to created to Autowire or to perform Dependency injection from within the Context

Comment: Definitely not. This is a standalong application, you should understand that all autowired beans that first must be managed by Spring, then the other thing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean no-xml conifg try this test

```
class T1 {
}

class T2 {
    @Autowired
    T1 t1;
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(T1.class, T2.class);
        ctx.refresh();
        System.out.println(ctx.getBean(T2.class).t1);
    }
}
```

it will show that T1 bean was injected into T2 bean